# matplotlib,Illegal format string two marker symbol

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

after i define all the variable of this monster line:
2330,-1.5,10:38:34,126.5,110.5,117.5,118,116.5,117,16117,22,117,5429,116.5,3649,116,3407,115.5,1835,115,2347,117.5,4671,118,4183,118.5,883,119,856,119.5,291,0,1,24,1000,25928305829,name,,,
i do like this(there are 3txt files):

```
try:
fileLine = stock+'.txt'        
Values = namedtuple('Values',
'number,rangep,timep,maxp,minp,openp,highp,lowp,closep,volume,curvolume,'
'openprice,openbvolume,bp1,bv1,bp2,bv2,bp3,bv3,bp4,bv4,bp5,bv5,sp1,sv1,sp2,sv2,sp3,'
'sv3,sp4,sv4,sp5,sv5,un1,un2,un3,un4,un5,namep,un6') 

with open(fileLine) as f:
 values = Values(*f.readline().split(','))

 fig = plt.figure()
 ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
 ax1.plot(values.timep, values.openp)
 ax1.plot(values.timep, values.highp)
 ax1.plot(values.timep, values.lowp)
 ax1.plot(values.timep, values.closep)
 plt.show()

 except Exception, e:
     print 'failed main loop',str(e)

 for stock in eachStock:
     graphData(stock)
```

and when i run this script it shows up :

failed main loop Illegal format string "117.5"; two marker symbols
failed main loop Illegal format string "23.8"; two marker symbols
failed main loop Unrecognized character 6 in format string

i just dont get it what is these line means

thanks a lot for helping!!

Comment: Instead of catching the exception and printing the message, just let the exception propagate. It'll be more informative.

Comment: This looks almost identical to a question that went by yesterday.  Do not delete and re-post questions.  Please edit this to reduce it to the _minimal_ amount of code which will replicate your problem.